# How do I have boost.python call a function to deallocate an object?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ function `Obj *new_object(const char *name)`.  It returns a new object, allocated from a private pool.  That object should be freed by `free_object(Obj *obj)` (and *not* by free() or delete).  How can I arrange my boost.python wrappers so that when the python obj goes out of scope (and gc is called) `free_obj` will be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most convenient way to do this would be to make sure your Boost.Python class declaration wraps both `Obj` and `boost::shared_ptr<Obj>`.

Then, use `boost::python::make_constructor` to instantiate the object upon construction. Your returned `boost::shared_ptr<Obj>` should set its own destructor (in your case, `free_object()`). Here is a sketch of this solution:

```
static boost::shared_ptr<Obj> init_from_c_string(const char* name) {
  //set destructor upon shared pointer initialisation
  return boost::shared_ptr<Obj>(new_object(name), &free_object);
}

//at your module scope, declare "Obj" like this
using namespace boost::python;
class_<Obj, boost::shared_ptr<Obj>>("Obj", "Obj docstring", no_init)
    .def("__init__", make_constructor(&init_from_c_string, default_call_policies(), (arg("name"))), "Constructs a new object with a given name.")
    //other .def and similar
;
```

Comment: Thanks -- To the folks who marked this dup, I agree the solution in the other question is about the same as this answer, but this one directly addresses my question about using a custom free method where the other question isn't really about that (though using that solution does work in my case).